# Skip FIleNotFoundError in django templates

Tags: django, templates

I encountered the following error in the template. How can skip this error. My code:

```
{% if obj.profile_pictures %}
<img src="{{ obj.profile_pictures.url }}" >
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'assets/img/alt_img.jpg' %}"">
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide all codes means url, models, views and settings and also share structure of your project